# Extract string from Pandas/Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to extract string from dataframe.

Raw data (dataframe)
**Column1:**
CA_1,CA_2,CA_3,BA_1,BA_2,BA_3,CA_4,BA_12,CA_6

Expected Output
**Column1:**
CA_1,CA_2,CA_3,CA_4,CA_6

How to produce the expected output? I tried pandas extract,extractall,contains but Im unable to produce the expected output.

Comment: `df.Column1.str.extract('^(CA_\d+)$')` ?  But what is the raw data? Is it a dataframe column or plain text? and what is the expected output? Is it going to be a dataframe column/series or plain text?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to remove all items that do not start with `CA_`?

I would use `str.replace` with a regex:

```
df['Column1'].str.replace(r'(?:(?!CA_)\b\w+,?)', '', regex=True)
```

Alternative with `split`/`explode`/`groupby.agg`:

```
(df['Column1'].str.split(',').explode()
 .loc[lambda s: s.str.startswith('CA_')]
 .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
)
```

output:

```
0    CA_1,CA_2,CA_3,CA_4,CA_6
Name: Column1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `str.replace` here:

```py
df["Column1"] = df["Column1"].str.replace(r'\b(?!CA_)[A-Z]+_\d+\b,?', '', regex=True)
```

Here is a regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SnXnow/1) showing that the replacement logic is working.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that OP's dataframe looks like the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['CA_1', 'CA_2', 'CA_3', 'BA_1', 'BA_2', 'BA_3', 'CA_4', 'BA_12', 'CA_6']})

[Out]:

  Column1
0    CA_1
1    CA_2
2    CA_3
3    BA_1
4    BA_2
5    BA_3
6    CA_4
7   BA_12
```

And assuming that OP wants the dataframe to have only the cells that contain the string `CA`, one can use `str.contains()` as follows

```
df_new = df[df['Column1'].str.contains('CA')]

[Out]:
  Column1
0    CA_1
1    CA_2
2    CA_3
6    CA_4
8    CA_6
```

Alternatively, one can use `str.startswith()`

```
df_new = df[df['Column1'].str.startswith('CA')]

[Out]:
  Column1
0    CA_1
1    CA_2
2    CA_3
6    CA_4
8    CA_6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
data = {
    'col1': ['CA_1','CA_2','CA_3','BA_1','BA_2','BA_3','CA_4','BA_12','CA_6']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
res = [dt for dt in data['col1'] if dt.startswith('CA_')]
print(res)
```

Result:

```
['CA_1', 'CA_2', 'CA_3', 'CA_4', 'CA_6']
```